# Look up Angular Type using a string

Tags: angular

I am making a drag-and-drop application with a toolbox from which you grab widgets and place them in a div.  I followed [this example](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#the-adcomponent-interface), and it works great so far, but now I want to be able to persist the configuration (to JSON) then reload it, and I'm stuck.

The hosting component gets a ComponentFactoryResolver.  From there I can say:

```
let factory = resolver.resovleComponentFactory( SomeComponent )
```

but my next step is to be able to do so using a name (string).  [ComponentFactoryResolver](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactoryResolver) takes a Type.  Is there some way to either look up the Type given its name?  I figure there must be some way to do so through the injection framework, but I haven't been able to make the connection via the API documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" is that you have to import each component that will be injected, in your host component.
Let's say:

```
import { SomeComponent1 } from '../component1';
import { SomeComponent2 } from '../component2';
import { SomeComponent3 } from '../component3';
```

One way to do what you want is relate them in an object

```
components = {
  'key1': SomeComponent1,
  'key2': SomeComponent2,
  'key3': SomeComponent3
}
```

and then use a string (in my following example, that is retrieved from another method) to get the component you want

```
const key = someMethodOrServiceThatGivesYouAString();
let factory = resolver.resovleComponentFactory( this.components[key] );
```

I know this is not what exactly you was looking for, but this is the way I'm doing this in an current app I'm working.

Comment: I found another way to do this looking at resolver['_factories'].keys()  but it feels too undocumented to be safe.  So I think I'll take your suggestion, thanks.